# Cannot connect to wired ethernet switch

Tags: ubuntu, networking, networkmanager

I am trying to connect my computer running Ubuntu 20.04.1 to an Ethernet switch. When I plug in the cable, then Settings->Network shows Connected-100 Mb/s. From the `ifconifg` and elsewhere I am able to see that Ethernet interface `eno1` has now an IP address, default route and DNS address which are obtained through DHCP. However, it is still unable to browse. When I boot the same computer using a Linux live USB (not Ubuntu), it is connected fine to the same device using the same Ethernet cable. I have tried static IP assignment as well without any success. I am unable to figure out what is missing. I have collected log details using `journalctl` and are appended below. One thing which seems to be missing from the logs is CONNECTED_GLOBAL, which I have seen with other connections. However, I am not sure if it has any effect. I will much appreciate any help to resolve this.

Here are the log details. From the logs also, you can see that it is unable to connect to daisy.ubuntu.com.

```
Jun 02 19:20:22 River kernel: e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eno1: NIC Link is Up 100 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: Rx/Tx
Jun 02 19:20:23 River kernel: e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eno1: 10/100 speed: disabling TSO
Jun 02 19:20:23 River kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eno1: link becomes ready
Jun 02 19:20:22 River NetworkManager[577]: <info>  [1622643622.9876] device (eno1): carrier: link connected
Jun 02 19:20:22 River NetworkManager[577]: <info>  [1622643622.9886] device (eno1): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'carrier-changed', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 02 19:20:22 River NetworkManager[577]: <info>  [1622643622.9909] policy: auto-activating connection 'Wired connection 1' (cdd9a516-d7a6-3705-97cd-1dd266f40234)
Jun 02 19:20:22 River NetworkManager[577]: <info>  [1622643622.9927] device (eno1): Activation: starting connection 'Wired connection 1' (cdd9a516-d7a6-3705-97cd-1dd266f40234)
Jun 02 19:20:22 River NetworkManager[577]: <info>  [1622643622.9930] device (eno1): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 02 19:20:22 River NetworkManager[577]: <info>  [1622643622.9945] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Jun 02 19:20:22 River NetworkManager[577]: <info>  [1622643622.9951] device (eno1): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 02 19:20:22 River NetworkManager[577]: <info>  [1622643622.9961] device (eno1): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 02 19:20:22 River NetworkManager[577]: <info>  [1622643622.9965] dhcp4 (eno1): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Jun 02 19:20:23 River NetworkManager[577]: <info>  [1622643623.0583] dhcp4 (eno1): option dhcp_lease_time      => '86400'
Jun 02 19:20:23 River NetworkManager[577]: <info>  [1622643623.0584] dhcp4 (eno1): option domain_name_servers  => '192.168.1.1'
Jun 02 19:20:23 River NetworkManager[577]: <info>  [1622643623.0584] dhcp4 (eno1): option expiry               => '1622730022'
Jun 02 19:20:23 River NetworkManager[577]: <info>  [1622643623.0584] dhcp4 (eno1): option ip_address           => '192.168.1.107'
Jun 02 19:20:23 River NetworkManager[577]: <info>  [1622643623.0584] dhcp4 (eno1): option requested_broadcast_address => '1'
Jun 02 19:20:23 River NetworkManager[577]: <info>  [1622643623.0584] dhcp4 (eno1): option requested_domain_name => '1'
Jun 02 19:20:23 River NetworkManager[577]: <info>  [1622643623.0584] dhcp4 (eno1): option requested_domain_name_servers => '1'
Jun 02 19:20:23 River NetworkManager[577]: <info>  [1622643623.0584] dhcp4 (eno1): option requested_domain_search => '1'
Jun 02 19:20:23 River NetworkManager[577]: <info>  [1622643623.0584] dhcp4 (eno1): option requested_host_name  => '1'
Jun 02 19:20:23 River NetworkManager[577]: <info>  [1622643623.0585] dhcp4 (eno1): option requested_interface_mtu => '1'
Jun 02 19:20:23 River NetworkManager[577]: <info>  [1622643623.0585] dhcp4 (eno1): option requested_ms_classless_static_routes => '1'
Jun 02 19:20:23 River NetworkManager[577]: <info>  [1622643623.0585] dhcp4 (eno1): option requested_nis_domain => '1'
Jun 02 19:20:23 River NetworkManager[577]: <info>  [1622643623.0585] dhcp4 (eno1): option requested_nis_servers => '1'
Jun 02 19:20:23 River NetworkManager[577]: <info>  [1622643623.0585] dhcp4 (eno1): option requested_ntp_servers => '1'
Jun 02 19:20:23 River NetworkManager[577]: <info>  [1622643623.0585] dhcp4 (eno1): option requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes => '1'
Jun 02 19:20:23 River NetworkManager[577]: <info>  [1622643623.0585] dhcp4 (eno1): option requested_root_path  => '1'
Jun 02 19:20:23 River NetworkManager[577]: <info>  [1622643623.0585] dhcp4 (eno1): option requested_routers    => '1'
Jun 02 19:20:23 River NetworkManager[577]: <info>  [1622643623.0585] dhcp4 (eno1): option requested_static_routes => '1'
Jun 02 19:20:23 River NetworkManager[577]: <info>  [1622643623.0586] dhcp4 (eno1): option requested_subnet_mask => '1'
Jun 02 19:20:23 River NetworkManager[577]: <info>  [1622643623.0586] dhcp4 (eno1): option requested_time_offset => '1'
Jun 02 19:20:23 River NetworkManager[577]: <info>  [1622643623.0586] dhcp4 (eno1): option requested_wpad       => '1'
Jun 02 19:20:23 River NetworkManager[577]: <info>  [1622643623.0586] dhcp4 (eno1): option routers              => '192.168.1.1'
Jun 02 19:20:23 River NetworkManager[577]: <info>  [1622643623.0586] dhcp4 (eno1): option subnet_mask          => '255.255.255.0'
Jun 02 19:20:23 River NetworkManager[577]: <info>  [1622643623.0586] dhcp4 (eno1): state changed unknown -> bound
Jun 02 19:20:23 River NetworkManager[577]: <info>  [1622643623.0631] device (eno1): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 02 19:20:23 River dbus-daemon[576]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.13' (uid=0 pid=577 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon " label="unconfined")
Jun 02 19:20:23 River systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Jun 02 19:20:23 River dbus-daemon[576]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Jun 02 19:20:23 River audit[1]: SERVICE_START pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='unit=NetworkManager-dispatcher comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
Jun 02 19:20:23 River systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Jun 02 19:20:23 River NetworkManager[577]: <info>  [1622643623.0769] device (eno1): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 02 19:20:23 River NetworkManager[577]: <info>  [1622643623.0772] device (eno1): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 02 19:20:23 River NetworkManager[577]: <info>  [1622643623.0779] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Jun 02 19:20:23 River NetworkManager[577]: <info>  [1622643623.0803] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
Jun 02 19:20:23 River NetworkManager[577]: <info>  [1622643623.0804] policy: set 'Wired connection 1' (eno1) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
Jun 02 19:20:23 River NetworkManager[577]: <info>  [1622643623.0811] device (eno1): Activation: successful, device activated.
Jun 02 19:20:33 River whoopsie[736]: [19:20:33] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
Jun 02 19:20:33 River systemd[1]: NetworkManager-dispatcher.service: Succeeded.
Jun 02 19:20:33 River audit[1]: SERVICE_STOP pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='unit=NetworkManager-dispatcher comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
Jun 02 19:20:43 River whoopsie[736]: [19:20:43] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
Jun 02 19:20:53 River whoopsie[736]: [19:20:53] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
Jun 02 19:20:58 River dbus-daemon[576]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.13' (uid=0 pid=577 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon " label="unconfined")
Jun 02 19:20:58 River systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Jun 02 19:20:58 River audit[1]: SERVICE_START pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='unit=NetworkManager-dispatcher comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
Jun 02 19:20:58 River dbus-daemon[576]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Jun 02 19:20:58 River systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Jun 02 19:21:08 River systemd[1]: NetworkManager-dispatcher.service: Succeeded.
Jun 02 19:21:08 River audit[1]: SERVICE_STOP pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='unit=NetworkManager-dispatcher comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
```

Comment: can you add the output of these commands in the question? `ip -br link; ip -br address; ip route; ip rule; ip route get 192.168.1.1`.

Comment: I really feel much embarrassed. I was not using the Ethernet interface and quite a time ago, I disabled `arp` over `eno1` using `ifconfig eno1 -arp` through a start up script which I had forgotten. So, `ip -br link` revealed `NOARP`. Therefore, I enabled it with `ifconfig eno1 arp`. This is working fine now. I would suggest to post an answer to this post to look for `arp` as a possible cause to this problem so that anyone like me can benefit. Much appreciation and many thanks.

Comment: Heh, since the information isn't actually available in the question yet, you'll have the task to answer your own question with this additional piece.